# Part of the mesh is not moving along with the rig in pose mode even though its one mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, parent

the whole character is one mesh, not parented to each other, just straight up joined together. when I rigged it, I assumed the shoulder armor with move with arm rig. I'm stuck now :'<

[image]

[image]

Here is the blend file if you guys want to check

[image]

Comment: well, shoulder plates are probably missing weight paint, go to weightpaint, select vertex group for shoulders and look if shoulder plates are weight paintet(if you are new, they should be red/colored, not blue) If they are blue, you need to weight paint them to shoulders

Comment: Ok just check the pose mode again and the whole armor is not connected with the rig, except for the helmet, but with out the head ???

Comment: can you share your file please?

Comment: how to share file? sorry, I'm new to blender and stack exchange :'>

Comment: Automatic weight is cool, but not perfect sometimes. You need to adjust weights manually. This video should help https://youtu.be/pAhbO7U1ID8

Comment: @Crantisz what if my character has armor? i want to move the character with its armor attached

Comment: use this for file share. I will look at it or someone else as well and we may find what is wrong
https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @MikoCG its taking a while to upload :<

Comment: I have uploaded the blend file :.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test of whether automatic weight painting worked is to select the character; enter weight paint mode; and enable the *Zero weight All* setting in viewport overlays:

[image: Viewport Overlays showing Zero weight all near the bottom]

In your case, this shows that the shoulder pad armor isn't painted in *any* Vertex group:

[image: character showing all black shoulder pads indicating that they're not included in any Vertex group]

To fix this, you must apply weight painting to the shoulder pads to match the bones and they should follow.  The left pad, for instance, should probably move when the left shoulder moves.  The bone name for the left shoulder is DEF-shoulder.L so select the Vertex Group with the same name and edit it:

[image: Character properties showing the left shoulder selected]

I suck at weight painting, so I'm going to cheat.  Back in edit mode, I island select (shortcut <kbd>L</kbd>) the left shoulder pad while I still have DEF-shoulder.L selected.  I then go to vertex groups and select assign.  Back in weight paint mode the shoulder pad now looks like this, because a weight of 1 shows up as all red:

[image: left shoulder pad is red showing it has weight of 1.]

Now when I rotate the shoulder bone the pad rotates with it.

Do the same for the right pad and DEF-shoulder.R and both pads now work.

Of course, you may want to have multiple bones, especially the upper arms, influence the shoulder pad, so you'll probably want to weight paint it for multiple vertex groups.

Comment: Thank you so much :3 being able to stumble into these problems and actually understanding how to solve it is really helpful :>

Comment: Quick question, would it be easier for me to rig this character if i remove the faces that are not visible like under the armor and connect it?

Comment: For such simple geometry it wouldn't matter very much.  If the character had a lot more vertices and you had to do a lot of weight painting to get the movement you wanted it would definitely be much easier.